# MySQL Update with JOIN - Why is it updating every field with only one value?

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE:** The problem is that table 1 has many rows that table 2 doesn't have, thats why the query updated a number of rows the first time I ran it, but running the query again, it only updated a single row. I don't know why it updated the rows that weren't included in the `JOIN` query.

I need to update two fields in table 1, with data from two fields in table 2.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE heroku_chemical_healtheffect h,
chebi2_compounds c  
SET h.chebi_id = c.chebi_accession, h.chebi_name = c.name
WHERE h.name = c.name
```

But it returned: `1 rows affected. (Query took 0.1351 seconds.)`

It inserted the same values (values from the first row in table 2) into each row of table 1:
[image: Rows updated]

I tried using the full syntax:

```
UPDATE heroku_chemical_healtheffect AS h
INNER JOIN chebi2_compounds AS c
ON h.name = c.name
SET h.chebi_id = c.chebi_accession, h.chebi_name = c.name
```

but the same thing happens. Did I put together the query the wrong way or something?

Heres `table 2`:

[image]

When I run a SELECT with JOIN query:

```
SELECT * FROM heroku_chemical_healtheffect AS h 
JOIN chebi2_compounds AS c 
ON h.name = c.name
```

[image]

I considered maybe it was an issue with indexes, so I removed the indexes from `h.chebi_id` and `h.chebi_name` and put indexes on `h.name` and `c.name` but it didn't change anything.

Whats strange is that it is not overwriting some of the values that are already in there. Some of the `h.chebi_id` fields have different values in them, and it is leaving them intact. Its only the blank fields that it updated. And when it inserted the same value into every row with a blank `h.name` field, it returned `1 row(s) affected`. Even though it updated a few hundred rows.

Heres what I mean:
[image]
It didn't update the row that had data in it, even though the data was different to what it updated all the blank rows with.

Comment: show us also the other table

Comment: Updated: Added table 2 to the original post.

Comment: It updated only one row because that's all the matching pairs of rows it can find. Remove the `SET` clause, replace `UPDATE` with `SELECT * FROM` to see the matching rows.

Comment: I did that, take a look at the updated post.

Comment: Oh, in this case, there was only one row that required updating. MySQL doesn't report as updated the rows where the value do not change. If you run the `UPDATE` again it should return `0 row(s) affected.`.

Comment: Yeah thats whats happening, its returning `0 row(s) affected`. Whats strange is that it is not overwriting some of the values that are already in there. Some of the `h.chebi_id` fields have different values in them, and it is leaving them intact. Its only the blank fields that it updated. And when it inserted the same value into every row with a blank `h.name` field, it returned `1 row(s) affected`. Even though it updated a few hundred rows.

Comment: It looks like you're right, I tried searching some of these fields from table 1, and they don't exist in table 2. So that would explain why its not finding matches for those fields. I don't understand how why it is joining these rows though, if they don't exist in table 2, they shouldn't be joined, and thus shouldn't be updated by the query.

Comment: Also, when I did the join with `SELECT * FROM h` it found a large number of matching rows, but looking at the joined tables, it looks like these rows have already been updated.

Comment: Yeah, I see what the issue is, table 1 contains lots of rows that table 2 doesn't have. So in this case, I need to set `h.chebi_id` and `h.chebi_name` to null for these rows.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE 
     heroku_chemical_healtheffect 
SET
  heroku_chemical_healtheffect.chebi_id = chebi2_compounds.chebi_accession, 
  heroku_chemical_healtheffect.chebi_name = chebi2_compounds.name

FROM
    heroku_chemical_healtheffect 
    INNER JOIN chebi2_compounds 
    ON heroku_chemical_healtheffect.name = chebi2_compounds.name
```

Comment: It gave me this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
    heroku_chemical_healtheffect AS h
    INNER JOIN chebi2_compounds AS' at line 7`

Comment: @nimourpristou There is no `FROM` in the [`UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). And the table(s) come before the `SET` clause.